How to prune this gifted rubber tree plant?
I was gifted this beautiful Rubber tree plant that’s unfortunately too wide for my space. It’s pretty leggy and I have no idea where to prune it. There are no leaves at the bottom unfortunately. Any help is really appreciated




This looks like an old well established Ficus elastica.  In the wild these become trees up to 100 feet tall. It will not get much taller inside than it is now.
You cannot go wrong with these plants.  They are tough and will bud out from old wood if you are patient.
You asked what the stalks are. The stems or trunks or stalks are the growth that come out of the soil that has smaller stems or leaves attached.
Fast method:  cut all the stalks off at the six inch level and reduce the amount of water until you see new buds on the stalks.
Slower method: cut one third of the stalks off at the six inch level. Four months later cut another third of the tall stalks off at the six inch level.  Repeat once more in another four months.
